# How to use django sitemap framework with mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-sitemaps

I have to generate a sitemap file for my application and I used django sitemap framework with an application of sqlite database,works like a charm and now when I try it on my app which runs on "mongodb" It doesn't works and all of the documentation are mainly focused on models,since mongodb don'e have a models is there any other way to use django sitemap framework with mongodb or any documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at one of these two.

http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django-mongo/

Comment: Thank u @Joey but the things is im just writting a sitemap generator for already created app with mongodb,so if I'm about to create means I can use the above links,this app is already done without using models.py